# Widget type interpretation in QField

Tags: qfield

I am using QGIS 3.22 and QField 2.0.16.

For my project I defined some attribute forms for my layers.
For one layer I want to get a drop down list offering the values pre-entered in the attribute table before.
So i defined "Eindeutige Werte" as widget type (in German: Bedienelemente) in QGIS.
When i test it in QGIS, the drop down list appears, in QField unfortunately not.
With Uluru 1.10 I never had problems with this..

Do I need to configure that functionality in QGIS in a different way now?

[image: grafic of "Eindeutige Werte"]

Comment: It's a "Value Map" Widget Type with the values generated by "Load Data from Layer"?

Comment: Hi, no it is the function called "Unique values" (manual description like this: Unique Values: You can select one of the values already used in the attribute table. If ‚Editable‘ is activated, a line edit is shown with autocompletion support, otherwise a combo box is used.)

Comment: I just found this topic. It seems that the interpretation of that widget type is not implemented yet in QField (https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/1931). Well, i thought it worked before but i was wrong. Thank you, i will find a workaround.